# Fourier Transform of Additive White Gaussian Noise?

Tags: fourier, awg

How do we calculate the Fourier Transform of Additive White Gaussian Noise? Since AWGN itself is random, does it mean that its Fourier transform is also random?

Comment: Do you mean Fourier Transform, as in the analytic evaluation of a function, or DFT, numerical evaluation of a finite record of values?

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the Discrete Fourier Transform of Additive White Gaussian Noise like this.

1) Fill a time vector with samples of AWGN
2) Take the DFT

The result will appear to be random.

How you interpret the resulting samples is another matter. Why are you taking the FT of AWGN in the first place?

It may be that you want to know how much energy is in each bandwidth of the AWGN, assuming it's being generated by an ergodic process. This will require some more processing. You will want to break your time record up into overlapping chunks, window each to avoid spectral leakage, then FT each separately. You will want to calculate the power in each bin, and then sum those powers over each bandwidth you want to examine, then average the power per bandwidth per frequency over all the transforms to reduce the variance.

Now you will start to get a result that describes the long term power spectrum of your AWGN.

If you want something else out of your FT processing of AGWN, then you will need to do something different with the results.

If you really mean FT, rather than DFT, you would be better off taking the question to the mathematics site.

Comment: Shouldn't the fft be bandlimited unity?

Comment: @ScottSeidman I'm afraid I don't understand your question. The individual words, yes, but I've never seen them used together like that.

Comment: The FFT of white noise is unity across the frequency spectrum, not random

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121358/how-to-prove-that-the-fourier-transform-of-white-noise-is-flat

Comment: @ScottSeidman The FFT of an impulse is unity across the power spectrum. The power spectrum of white noise, when taken as I specify in my answer, will certainly approach flat as the number of chunks the input is broken into increases. However, the power spectrum of a single FFT of a finite record of AWGN is most certainly not unity. For a star, the output of an FFT is complex voltage, not power. When you take the powers of the results of a single FFT, the variance of the powers is equal to the mean power itself, very noisy. Have you ever investigated this sort of thing in MATLAB?

Comment: @ScottSeidman ... however, I may have misunderstood the OP, and read FFT where he wrote FT. I don't do analytic FTs, only DFTs, where the issues I talk about arise. I'll ask him. For the moment I've modifed my answer to explicitly be about DFTs.

Comment: The spectrum of a finite record of white noise would be the convolution of unity and a sinc funtion in the frequency domain.  There is an answer, and "approach unity" and "appear random" are two very different things.

Comment: @ScottSeidman well there I'd disagree with you, you've obviously never done practical spectral analysis of noise-like signals. I stand by the DFT of a single of a single record of AWGN looking random. As you let its length increase to infinity, it stays just as random, but the resolution increases. As you increase the number of sub-FFTs and average, the variance decreases and it becomes flatter. Summing the power across several bins to increase the resolution bandwidth also decreases the variance of the power estimates. The FT of an ergodic noise process is something else, as in your link.

Comment: In math, white noise *may* be Gaussian white noise (or not.) Since Gaussian white noise is usually what's meant in electronics (since that is how related physical processes work), then it will be the case that the Fourier coefficients will themselves also be Gaussian white noise with zero mean and the same variance. As I understand it, anyway. So I think I agree with Neil.